# Interview - Write a program to remove even elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I was asked this today and i know the answer is damn sure simple but he kept me the twist to the last.

#### Question

Write a program to remove even numbers stored in `ArrayList` containing `1 - 100`.

#### I just said wow

Here you go this is how i have implemented it.

```
ArrayList source = new ArrayList(100);
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    source.Add(i);
}


for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(source[i]) % 2 ==0)
    {
        source.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

//source contains only Odd elements
```

#### The twist

He asked me what is the computational complexity of this give him a equation. I just did and said this is Linear directly proportional to N (Input).

he said : hmmm.. so that means i need to wait longer to get results when the input size increases am i right? `Yes sirr you are`

Tune it for me, make it `Log(N)` try as much as you can he said. I failed miserably in this part.

- Hence come here for the right logic, answer or algorithm to do this.

**note:** He wanted no Linq, No extra bells and whistles. Just plain loops or other logic to do it

Comment: LINQ won't help, it just keep those dirty works behind the scene

Comment: Never mind. you can't use LINQ to remove stuff. And working with arrays is not always very efficient.

Comment: Since the result is O(N), and you remove O(N) elements, you can't get better than O(N).

Comment: Most likely what he wanted to hear was that it is not possible (with the reasoning) :) or just wanted to see your approach or thought process.

Comment: Since `i` is always incremented, won't this miss every 2nd successive even item?

Comment: Not an answer, but using two integer arrays with no boxing, conversion or internal redimensioning would be the real way to optimize this algorithm...just saying.

Comment: @Deeptechtons:  I think it works by coincidence.  If you initialize your list with `source.Add(2)` does it end up empty?

Comment: @AdamLiss I think you misunderstood the question ( or have i made it that way), the numbers are inserted sequentially upto 100. So there would be no repitition :)

Comment: @Deeptechtons If so, you don't need to check the elements, but only the current index, to be `% 2 == 0`.

Comment: @AdamLiss The thing that makes it work is that odd and even numbers alternate in the original list, so skipping every second number doesn't hurt.

Comment: @YoryeNathan No, the index of 34, say, doesn't remain the same during the removal pass.

Comment: @DanielFischer Normally I would agree, but read his comment that came before mine. Oh I'm sorry, reverse-loop is also needed. Yes.

Comment: @Tudor No. Even if he wanted to i would not. But i would love to know how it could lead to a effective solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's think it this way:

The number of delete actions you are doing is, forcely, the half of array lenght (if the elements are stored in array). So the complexity is at least O(N) .

The question you received let me suppose that your professor wanted you to reason about different ways of storing the numbers.

Usually when you have log complexity you are working with different structures, like graphs or trees.

The only way I can think of having logartmic complexity is having the numbers stored in a tree (ordered tree, b-tree... we colud elaborate on this), but it is actually out of the constraints of your exam (sotring numbers in array).

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @Daniele.B It certainly does. I should be marking this answer. But have do voteup others for technical points to their answer :)

Comment: +1 As you say, strictly speaking the question has no answer; because the question states that the input is an `arraylist`, as it specifys this type restriction any action to find the items to remove or to populate a new list based on the valid values will still be `O(n/2)` = `O(n)`, unless you can save time with an infinate number of multiple threads

Answer (score 5):

I dare say that the complexity is in fact O(N^2), since removal in arrays is O(N) and it can potentially be called for each item.

So you have O(N) for the traversal of the array(list) and O(N) for each removal => O(N) * O(N).

Since it does not seem clear, I'll explain the reasoning. At each step a removal of an item may take place (assuming the worst case in which every item must be removed). In an array the removal is done by shifting. Hence, to remove the first item, I need to shift all the following N-1 items by one position to the left:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6...
<---
2 3 4 5 6...
```

Now, at each iteration I need to shift, so I'm doing `N-1 + N-2 + ... + 1 + 0` shifts, which gives a result of `(N) * (N-1) / 2` (arithmetic series) giving a final complexity of O(N^2).

Comment: I didnot down vote you & I don't like downvoting too. But removal is by index hence always 1 and not O(N) as you say

Comment: @Deeptechtons: And how exactly do you think this "removal by index" is done? By shifting. Assume I want to remove the 3rd item. Then each of the 4th, 5th...Nth items needs to be shifted to the left by 1 position.

Comment: @Deeptechtons.  See the documentation for ArrayList.RemoteAt().  It's documented as O(n): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.removeat.aspx

Comment: Rather than arguing, why not check the docs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.removeat.aspx  See the "Remarks" section, which explicitly says O(n).

Comment: This is completely wrong. You only need to shift any given item in the array at most once, at constant cost.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: No problem. Can you use another array to solve it or only the original one?

Comment: @Michael J.Barber: Please demonstrate this because I don't know what you mean. And the documentation linked above clearly states it's O(N) so doing O(N) N times gives what?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber How so? 99 must be shifted when removing 2, when 4, when 6, ... if you use `RemoveAt`.

Comment: Keep track of the index into which you'll insert the next value. Iterate through the array. If you encounter an even number, write it at the index and increase the index. If you encounter an odd number, do nothing. You go through once, you move each even number either zero times or once, you don't move odd numbers at all. That's O(N) -- which is, of course, not the O(log N) asked for in the question, anyway.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Everybody else was talking about the OP's algorithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer The answer provided says nothing about `RemoveAt`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber The answer talks about the complexity of OP's algorithm. Of course, what you suggested is the good algorithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I didn't get that from the answer.

Comment: @Michael J.Barber: I was talking about what the OP wrote, not alternative custom solutions.

Comment: @Tudor OK, fair enough; I thought you were trying to provide an answer  on its own merits, rather than commentary on the specifics of the OP's program.

Comment: @Michael J.Barber: I felt that this complexity clarification is very much needed since we were starting from an obviously false assumption that the original solution is linear time.

Comment: That's what comments are for.

Comment: @Michael J.Barber: I would post a comment if you tell me how to squeeze all the above in 600 characters. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get noticeably better performance if you keep two indexes, one to the current read position and one to the current write position.

```
int read = 0
int write = 0;
```

The idea is that read looks at each member of the array in turn; write keeps track of the current end of the list. When we find a member we want to delete, we move read forwards, but not write.

```
for (int read = 0; read < source.Count; read++) {
  if (source[read] % 2 != 0) {
    source[write] = source[read];
    write += 1;
  }
}
```

Then at the end, tell the ArrayList that its new length is the current value of `write'.

This takes you from your original O(n^2) down to O(n).

(note: I haven't tested this)

Comment: Question is this : "Write a program to remove even numbers stored in ArrayList containing 1 - 100", you misinterpret the question.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri oops, you're right, I had it backwards. Good catch.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I really don't understand question and don't understand where is error in lain's code. Can you give me input/output for 1-10? (and result of lain's 'wrong' code)

Comment: @nsinreal: click on the link in "edited 1 hour ago", you'll see the error Iain fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use an ArrayList and actively have to remove the entries (instead if not adding them in the first place)

Not incrementing by i + 1 but i + 2 will remove your need to check if it is odd.

```
for (int i = source.Count - 1 ; i > 0; i = i i 2)
{
   source.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

**Edit**: I know this will only work if `source` contains the entries from 1-100 in sequential order.

Comment: He means removing the numbers that are even, not at even positions. An even if it were so, it would not improve the overall complexity.

Comment: Well, that's true, but he did say it contains 1-100 and the way he adds them means they are sequential. And it is more "tuned" than the initial version.

Comment: @Brunner I think you've missed the point.  If the array contains 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, you'd need to remove the 1st, 2nd, 5th, and 6th elements, which all contain even numbers.

Comment: @Brunner this would reduce to `N/2` which i suggested, but then he insisted on `log(N)` :(

Comment: @AdamLiss It sounded to me that it's up to the implementation how the entries are added, aka no duplicates and in sequential order.

Comment: @Deeptechtons This is the best I can think of when it comes to tuning the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the data structure or making some assumption on the way items are stores inside the ArrayList, I can't see how you'll avoid checking the parity of each and every member (hence at least `O(n)` complexity). Perhaps the interviewer simply wanted you to tell him it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the given solution is that it starts from the beginning, so the entire list must be shifted each time an item is removed:

```
Initial List:       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 98, 99
                         /  /  /  ///  /
After 1st removal:  1, 3, 4, 5, ..., 98, 99, <empty>
                            /  ///  /   /
After 2nd removal:  1, 3, 5, ..., 98, 99, <empty>, <empty>
```

I've used the slashes to try to show how the list shifts after each removal.

You can reduce the complexity (and eliminate the bug I mentioned in the comments) simply by **reversing the order of removal:**

```
for (int i = source.Count-1; i >= 0; --i)  {
  if (Convert.ToInt32(source[i]) % 2 == 0) {
    // No need to re-check the same element during the next iteration.
    source.RemoveAt(--i);
  }
}
```

Comment: @AdamLiss try it , your's leads to bug :)

Comment: @AdamLiss And that's still O(n^2) too :-)

Comment: @nsinreal, I think interviewer was jokking, because its impossible to have log(n), because we have O(n) items to remove, so it can't be better than O(n), never, also in arrayList it couldn't be better than O(n^2).

Comment: @Saeed Amiri: O(n) in arrayList is possible. There was a comment from Michael J. Barber how to do. Starts with "Keep track of the"…

Comment: @nsinreal, Barber's answer is just misinterpretation of question.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri : well, I writed that as confirmation that O(n) in arrayList is possible

Comment: @nsinreal, See my comment on lain answer, no it's impossible to do this with arrayList.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible **IF** you have unlimited parallel threads available to you.

Suppose that we have an array with `n` elements.  Assign one thread per element.  Assume all threads act in perfect sync.

1. Each thread decides whether its element is even or odd.  (Time `O(1)`.)
2. Determine how many elements below it in the array are odd.  (Time `O(log(n))`.)

   1. Mark a 0 or 1 in an second array depending whether you are even or odd at the same index.  So each one is a count of odds at that spot.
   2. If your index is odd, add the previous number.  Now each entry is a count of odds in the current block of 2 up to yourself
   3. If your index mod 4 is 2, add the value at the index below, if it is 3, add the answer 2 indexes below.  Now each entry is a count of odds in the current block of 4 up to yourself.
   4. Continue this pattern with blocks of `2**i` (if you're in the top half add the count for the bottom half) `log2(n)` times - now each entry in this array is the count of odds below.
3. Each CPU inserts its value into the correct slot.
4. Truncate the array to the right size.

I am willing to bet that something like this is the answer your friend has in mind.

Comment: @Deeptechtons - could you report back on what your friend says?  I want to know if I figured out his cheating twist correctly.

Comment: Hi btilly, I have yet to meet him again. Tomorrow i shall come with an answer :)